# Override And Call Base Property Set Method

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

Is it possible to override a property but also call the base property set method?

For example; in the class `Child` I want to override the `this[]` operator but also call the base `this[]` operator aswell?

```
public class Base {

    protected Branch properties = Branch.EmptyBranch; 

    public virtual Branch this[string attribKey] {
        get
        {
            return properties[attribKey]; // will return Branch.EmptyBranch if key doesn't exist
        }
        set
        {
            properties[attribKey] = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Child {

    protected uint dimensions = 3;

    public override Branch this[string attribKey] {
        // No need to override get as we dont have any custom functionality
        set
        {
            // Can I call the base 'set' method?
            base[attribKey];

            // Add custom functionality
            if (attribKey.Equals("data_2d"))
                dimensions = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the base set method like this and it shouldn't cause any problems:

```
public override Branch this[string attribKey] {

        set
        {                
            base[attribKey] = value;    

            if (attribKey.Equals("data_2d"))
                dimensions = 2;
        }
    }
```